# How to create history using trigger, column name, before and after value, who modified, date and time?

Tags: sql, t-sql, history

I have a two tables one is main and other one is for history, having the same schema with different records apart from the unique one.

I want to create a query which can tell me which column was updated and what the before and after values along with who has updated and what time.

Please see below. Can anyone help me to get this done using SQL?

```
UniqueID Field Modified  Before Value   After Value     updatedby:  Change Date
111 Company Name     Exxon Mobile   ExxonMobileTest Dev     1/13/2014
122 Account Category Focused    Pursuit         Jeff        1/13/2014
```

Answer (score 0):

Make and audit table that mirrors the one you want to log, then every new row you insert into the audit signifies a change in data, use this trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[mytrigger]
   ON  [dbo].[mytable]
   AFTER INSERT,DELETE,UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;
declare @ERR_TXT char(255),@ER int,@RC int

if (select COUNT(*) from inserted) <> 0 -- validate the new data
begin
 -- do stuff to check new data if needed
end

if (select count(*) from inserted) = (select count(*) from deleted) -- update
begin
INSERT INTO [DB].[dbo].[myAudit]
           ... (all columns)
SELECT ... (all columns)
    from inserted
end

if (select count(*) from inserted) = 0 and (select count(*) from deleted) <> 0 -- delete
begin
INSERT INTO [DB].[dbo].[myAudit]
           ... (all columns)
SELECT ... (all columns)
    from deleted
end

if (select count(*) from inserted) <> 0 and (select count(*) from deleted) = 0 -- insert
begin
INSERT INTO [DB].[dbo].[myAudit]
           ... (all columns)
SELECT ... (all columns)
    from inserted
end

END
```

This works well for me. You can use some of the server functions to see who did the transactions, like SUSER_ID() & GETDATE().

Comment: If I already have all this information in history table, I just need to compare the data from main table and get the records in that format.

Comment: select * from myTable a join myAudit b on a.keyField=b.keyField order by audit_date